# Is there any good reason to have Sitecore Media url's including tilde?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6, sitecore-media-library

I could see [blog post](http://sitecoreblog.alexshyba.com/2011/10/sitecore-media-library-performance.html) from 2011 recommending using "-" instead of "~".

What is the best practice to write media URL in Sitecore 6.5 on .NET 4.0/IIS7.5? Should I keep default /~/media/ or follow blog post advice using /-/media/ or while I am there, why not just use /media/?

Comment: I'd like the answer to this question as well. A quick search reveals quite an interesting list of results. http://search.yahoo.com/search?p=IIS+windows+8+tilde+character+%7E&b=&fr=ie8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect the use of ~ is for legacy reasons. The current recommendation is to use `-/media` as you point out, but you could use whatever you wanted and it would work. The issue you have just using `/media/` is if there is any other item with that as part of the name then it will trigger the media handler, rather than serving up your content for example.

For example, as request for `/blah/blah/blah/-/media/images/logo.png` will serve up the image correctly, `/about/media/news/2013/12/20/sitecore.aspx` should in fact serve up a page but will trigger the media handler and return a 404 just using /media/. So if you are going to use something else then make sure it is unique, you may need to enforce it since content editors can be a bit funny about remembering things like this.

Since you are currently using Sitecore 6.5 then I can assume you have existing content. Make sure you leave the existing `~/media` trigger to allow your Rich Text fields to continue to work

> If you update the Media.MediaLinkPrefix setting on a system that
>   already has some content in a database, Sitecore may not update the
>   values in all Rich Text Editor fields that contain values in the old
>   formats, including inline images and links to media items.

[Sitecore Idiosyncrasies: Media URLs](http://www.sitecore.net/Community/Technical-Blogs/John-West-Sitecore-Blog/Posts/2012/12/Sitecore-Idiosyncrasies-Media-URLs.aspx)

I would probably go ahead and set `Media.RequestExtension` to an empty string so that image urls are served up with the correct media extension too.

Answer (score 1):

I know this problem appear just when are you using .Net Framework 2.0

Please see next [link](http://soroush.secproject.com/downloadable/iis_tilde_shortname_disclosure.txt) . 
   If you run your website under .Net Framework 4.0 and IIS 7.5 you don't have this vulnerability.

Also this [document](https://www.google.ch/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCwQFjAA&url=http://www.exploit-db.com/download_pdf/19527/&ei=7za0Ut37FcfLswbD5YCABw&usg=AFQjCNEcaluvju68nXlK8gdLn4Ji9Unt-Q&sig2=u-wtaOKSaADHP1ch8gYVmQ&bvm=bv.58187178,d.Yms) explain a little bit about using of tilde.

Also you can check John West [blog](http://www.sitecore.net/Community/Technical-Blogs/John-West-Sitecore-Blog/Posts/2012/12/Sitecore-Idiosyncrasies-Media-URLs.aspx) about /~/media

So the conclusion is use  -/media for media files.

Answer (score -1):

For projects using Sitecore 7.2, you may want to stick to using a tilde or apply the hot-fix mentioned in the following KB article.

https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/998758